# EC2 docker issue on cloud 9

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9, docker-aws

I'm getting two sets of different docker images. One set when I ssh into my ec2 instance and one in my cloud9 environment. Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? I basically need one of the images I created in docker to send to ec2

[Docker images after I ssh into ec2 instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0dij.png)

[Docker images in my cloud9 environment that I'm attempting to upload to EC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXYJ5.png)

I'm attempting to run this command in my ec2 instance but get an error that the image is not being found...

4. Run the following command:

```
docker run --rm \
    -it --name db-setup\
    <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/<repo-or-image-name>:<version-tag> \
    bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: Do you connect to the same EC2 instance on which Cloud9 is running? I wondering why do you not upload the docker image into ECR container registry in order to share it?

Comment: no im connecting to a separate EC2 instance I created in cloud9 instance, the image im trying to use is in ECR container registry

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for exec, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' this is the error I get